# SKView Background Image Not Showing = Black

Tags: swift, uicolor, skscene

I am attempting to use a pattern as a background color for an SKScene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let backgroundImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "BackgroundSquare.png")!
//        print(backgroundImage)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: backgroundImage)
}
```

... but the background always comes out black. I have attempted with the "BackgroundSquare.png as a white square and also with a transparent background but with no luck. I know that `backgroundImage` is not nil (which is why I have the `print()` line.
Am I using `UIColor(patternImage:)` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

SKScene does not support pattern images. You can do something similar using a shader, but you won't be able to use that API with any effect. Why there's no warning? No idea.